# Is there a way to edit column type after already creating it?

Tags: list-view, column

[image]

This is my column view. My goal is to allow my team to enter in "tickets" with each column filled out and we can have a comprehensive list of tickets that are linked to issues within our business environment.

The problem that I'm running into, is that once you've created a column, you can no longer edit or change the column type afterwards. For an example, my "Application" column was created to allow single strings of text, but now I want to set it as a drop-down list of preset items.

Is there a way to edit these columns or do I need to delete them and recreate them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a degree of flexibility with some of the column types. You can convert a single line of text column to a choice field. Go into the List Settings and click on your Application field. Tick the radio button to Choice and supply your predetermined values. Click OK/Save and you should be set.